# CSS: min-width and small screens

Tags: css

In my CSS

```
body{
overflow-y:scroll;
min-width: 1024px;
}
```

What have I expected? That if screen size is less than 1024px, then there will be gorizontal scrollbar, and elements won't cover each other (1024px - minimal width, with which my site looks pretty as expected).

But when I test it with some resolution testers, it actually turns out that it doesn't change anything.

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting the [`min-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-width) of the `body`. That means that the width **can't** be smaller than your `min-width`.

You probably want to use [media querys](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/).

Like for example:

**CSS**

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
    body{
        overflow-x:scroll; /* horizontal */
        /* overflow-y:scroll; */ /* vertical */
    }
}
```

This tells us if the **window** width is *smaller then 1024px*, then add an `overflow-y:scroll` to the `body`.

Comment: Thanks, and this will prevent body rendering on 640x480 screen as it width is 640? I mean, there will be 640px + 364 of scrolling right?

Comment: Horizontal scrolling would be overflow-x as noted above. But please, for the sale of site visitors don't do that. Horizontal scrolling sucks. You should do some research on responsive web design.

Comment: @ChrisFerdinandi noted and updated. And I agree, I would suggest you to use _media querys_ for responsive web design.

Answer (score 1):

For horizontal scroll you shoud use `overflow-x:scroll;` and not `overflow-y`.
it adds vertical scroll to the content. here is example if it will help you http://jsfiddle.net/sMtmD/